# Neo4j/Cypher - Randomly match nodes

Tags: random, neo4j, cypher, seeding

I need to seed a Neo4j database and have random `Person`s join random `Organization`s. I have the following Cypher query:

```
MATCH (p:Person), (o:Organization)
WITH p, o
WHERE rand() < 0.1
MERGE (p)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(o)
```

The problem is that this query is giving each person a 10% chance to join **all** organizations. How can I get this query to generate a random number for every combination of `Person`s and `Organization`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's odd that the planner executed it that way. To fix this, let's project out a random number with each combination and do the filtering after:

```
MATCH (p:Person), (o:Organization)
WITH p, o, rand() as random
WHERE random < 0.1
MERGE (p)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(o)
```